# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.config' has no attribute 'list_physical_devices'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Am using Tensorflow 2.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. On running

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

I get the above error. What is the workaround for this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Run `tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')` to see all the GPUs

or

run `tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices(device_type=None)` to see all the devices

You can also use `tf.test.is_gpu_available()`. It says True if it detects the available gpu.

Answer (score 0):

The updated answer should be for Tensorflow 2.0 is `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`